# Sonar parsing test-results

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm working on a groovy project. I'm trying to generate cobertura-reports on Sonar.
But I'm having an issue with test-results.
It's giving an error, saying that

```
Sensor GroovySurefireSensor...
**parsing** /home/jenkins/workspace/myproject/build/test-results
WARN  - Resource not found: xxx.xxx.myproject.xxx.xxx
WARN  - Resource not found: xxx.xxx.myproject.xxx.xxx
WARN  - Resource not found: xxx.xxx.myproject.xxx.xxx
WARN  - Resource not found: xxx.xxx.myproject.xxx.xxx
WARN  - Resource not found: xxx.xxx.myproject.xxx.xxx
WARN  - Resource not found: xxx.xxx.myproject.xxx.xxx
WARN  - Resource not found: xxx.xxx.myproject.xxx.xxx
INFO  - Sensor GroovySurefireSensor done: 12 ms
```

FYI: I am able to generate Cobertura reports and test-reports on SonarQube but Technical debt and issues showing "zero"

---

Here is my sonar-project properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=myproject

sonar.projectName=myproject

sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=src/main

groovy.sonar.tests=src/test

sonar.language=grvy

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.surefire.reportsPath=build/test-results

sonar.junit.reportsPath=build/test-results

sonar.groovy.cobertura.reportPath=build/reports/cobertura/coverage.xml
```

---

Any suggestions?

Comment: Even though I comment out `groovy.sonar.tests`,there is no difference I found.